# QString simplify not removing whitespace in JSON string

Tags: json, qt, qt5, qstring, removing-whitespace

I have a function which passes a `QString` containing JSON to a Qt Tree View.
Part of the JSON contains white space character `\r\n` which I want to remove as it creates odd symbols in the tree view.

```
void JsonViewer::setJson(const QString &json) {
    auto cleanJson = json.simplified();
    jsonModel->loadJson(QByteArray::fromStdString(cleanJson.toStdString()));
}
```

`QString::simplified()` appears to work fine on shorter test strings (the JSON can be around 2k characters). Looking at `cleanJson` in the debugger it still has white space characters and is identical to the original string.

Is there a reason that it wouldn't work on longer strings, or possibly issues with different types of encoding? (The JSON is ultimately coming from a network source).

Edit:

This also seems to be true for `.replace("\r\n", "")` and `.remove(\r\n")`

Comment: If the function fails for very large strings then you can divide the string into small parts, apply the function and then join it.

Comment: Years ago I found that the limit on QString is around 2GB. I found that out using a QString to export a text SQLITE database dump (contains INSERT statements).